# How to close a pubnub connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pubnub

I'm using pubnub in a node.js project. I can initialize pubnub and publish a message like:

**Node.js**

```
var PUBNUB = require('pubnub');
var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
  publish_key   : 'demo',
  subscribe_key : 'demo'
});

var CHANNEL = 'test1234';

pubnub.subscribe({
  channel: CHANNEL,
  message: function (message) {
    console.log('Received message:', message);

    // unsubscribe again
    pubnub.unsubscribe({channel: CHANNEL});

    // PROBLEM: The node.js process does not exit because pubnub is still 
    //          active. How to close the pubnub connection so it's completely 
    //          gone from memory?
  },
  connect: function () {
    // send a test message
    pubnub.publish({channel: CHANNEL, message: 'hello world!'});
  }
});
```

But how can I close this pubnub instance? So that it's gone from memory and event loop and does not keep the node.js process running.

I can't find anything in the API documentation, and tried `pubnub.close()`, `pubnub.destroy()`, and `pubnub.disconnect()` without success.

Comment: Afaik your snippet doesn't establish a connection yet, usually you'll establish one by subscribing to a channel and close it by unsubscribing again. See the examples: https://github.com/pubnub/javascript/blob/master/examples/dev-console/dev-console.html

Comment: Thanks. I have posted a full code example better explaining the question. The point is that in node.js the process never ends because pubnub is still active in memory.

Comment: pubnub.unsubscribe() should be removing the subscribe process. Can you please contact us at support@pubnub.com so we can work closer with you on a solution (we'll report our findings here.)

Comment: @Geremy thanks for your response. Good to know that the process should automatically close when unsubscribed from all channels. I've send a message with this issue to support@pubnub.com

Comment: @JosdeJong I'm having the same issue. Were you able to resolve it with the help of pubnub support? If so, what did you do?

Comment: Yes I've had an email conversation with them, I offered a [pull request](https://github.com/pubnub/javascript/pull/40) with a fix, but they solved it in an other way. The code above correctly exits on pubnub v3.7.8.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved in a newer version of pubnub (current is v3.7.8).